# Node exporter is not starting on a linux machine

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I installed node exporter to a linux machine. When is run the status command it shows error.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start node_exporter
sudo systemctl status node_exporter


 node_exporter.service - Node Exporter
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/node_exporter.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-10-06 06:39:16 UTC; 7s ago
    Process: 1071861 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node_exporter (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1071861 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 06 06:39:16 dse-ci-test1 node_exporter[1071861]: time="2022-10-06T06:39:16Z" level=info msg=" - time" source="node_exp>
Oct 06 06:39:16 dse-ci-test1 node_exporter[1071861]: time="2022-10-06T06:39:16Z" level=info msg=" - timex" source="node_ex>
Oct 06 06:39:16 dse-ci-test1 node_exporter[1071861]: time="2022-10-06T06:39:16Z" level=info msg=" - uname" source="node_ex>
Oct 06 06:39:16 dse-ci-test1 node_exporter[1071861]: time="2022-10-06T06:39:16Z" level=info msg=" - vmstat" source="node_e>
Oct 06 06:39:16 dse-ci-test1 node_exporter[1071861]: time="2022-10-06T06:39:16Z" level=info msg=" - xfs" source="node_expo>
Oct 06 06:39:16 dse-ci-test1 node_exporter[1071861]: time="2022-10-06T06:39:16Z" level=info msg=" - zfs" source="node_expo>
Oct 06 06:39:16 dse-ci-test1 node_exporter[1071861]: time="2022-10-06T06:39:16Z" level=info msg="Listening on :9100" sourc>
Oct 06 06:39:16 dse-ci-test1 node_exporter[1071861]: time="2022-10-06T06:39:16Z" level=fatal msg="listen tcp :9100: bind: >
Oct 06 06:39:16 dse-ci-test1 systemd[1]: node_exporter.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 06 06:39:16 dse-ci-test1 systemd[1]: node_exporter.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

Comment: this is my node_exporter.service [Unit]
Description=Node Exporter
After=network.target

[Service]
User=node_exporter
Group=node_exporter
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node_exporter

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: This is a question you would rather have to ask to the maintainer of node_exporter. I guess he will ask releavant question such as the version of node exporter and the flavor of OS. This question is unlikely to be relvant to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I think you already have prometheus-node-exporter service, try to check your [ipserver]:9100 on your browser, if it shows metric, it means that it's already worked